# trackbar in visualbasic windowsform cannot be deselected

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am making a basic lunar lander program in visual basic using windows forms. I have a track bar to adjust thrust. I am also using WASD to control the landers direction. WASD works fine if I haven't used the track bar to adjust the thrust. But the moment I adjust the thrust the trackbar becomes selected and I cannot use the WASD keys anymore. What do I need to do to fix this issue?[picture of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4EQW.jpg)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on Ahmed's comment, if you set KeyPreview to true then the form will experience the key events before any selected control on the form does.

```
Public Sub New() MyBase.New()

    Me.KeyPreview = True

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    
    'put your WASD code here instead (if it isn't already in form's keydown)

    'stop the event being passed to a selected control
    e.Handled = True
End Sub
```